# Erro ao tentar mudar cursor durante algoritmo C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, cursor

Olá,
Estou desenvolvendo um software em C# para ajudar na digitalização de fotos antigas, e no meio de um dos algoritmos para processar as imagens, quero que o cursor mude para o modo de carregamento para que o usuário saiba quando o sistema está processando.

O que eu fiz foi inserir desta forma logo no início da função:

```
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

        int count = 0;
        int n = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

        foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            MotherImage mImage = new MotherImage(file);
            mImage.targetImage.CalculateDataIntensity();
            mImage.CreateMap();

           ...
```

O único porém é que recebo esta mensagem de erro do Visual Studio:

Mensagem de erro:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code

Detalhes do erro:

> {Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation
>   timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function
>   evaluation.}

O comando está errado? Alguma ideia de como proceder?

Comment: Com esse código não dá pra ver erro algum. Poste onde ocorre o erro de fato.

Comment: Desculpe, o erro vem diretamente da linha "this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;"

Comment: Que tecnologia está usando?

Comment: Como assim tecnologia? Pra interface? É C# WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por acaso você está mexendo em outras threads para fazer processamento paralelo?

Sugiro colocar isso em volta do comando do cursor:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        }));
```

Comment: Obrigado rafascar!! Funcionou sim, mas voce sabe se é o método mais adequado? não dá nenhum atraso desfavorável?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você deveria usar binding...

no .xaml

```
 Cursor="{Binding cursor}"
```

no .cs

```
 private Cursor _cursor;   
 public Cursor cursor
    {
        get { return _cursor; }
        set
        {
            _cursor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("cursor");
        }
    }
```

assim toda vez que cursor receber algo mudará no bindind também.